# Too many redirects when forcing https on a template group

Tags: htaccess, ssl, charge

I'm having some trouble with forcing https on a given template group.  If I use the following, I get the "too many redirects" error. If I comment out my "force SSL" conditions, everything else works fine (removal of www, removal of index.php, etc.). Can anyone point out what's out of place here?  This is for a site hosted with EngineHosting (if that plays any role here) and I am using the Charge add-on with "force SSL" turned on (which forces https:// on the post value on the module's generated form)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

# Enable Rewrite Engine
# ------------------------------
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Redirect www Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect index.php Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} !/my_system_folder/.*
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,L]

# Forse SSL on Donate Section Requests
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond $1 ^(donate) [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

# Standard ExpressionEngine Rewrite
# ------------------------------
RewriteCond $1 !\.(css|js|gif|jpe?g|png) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

</IfModule>

#add Expires
# ------------------------------
FileETag MTime Size
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
  <filesmatch "\.(jpg|png|css|js|jpeg|woff|ttf|svg|eot|gif)$">
       ExpiresActive on
       ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
   </filesmatch>
</IfModule>
```

I just want to force SSL on any /donate URI.

Answer (score 0):

Whilst not answering directly, I've always used force SSL module and it just works: http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dm-force-ssl

Comment: I tried using the add-on but it had no effect. I followed the install instructions - which were pretty simple - and it just didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0):

I think I ended up hard coding the domain into the redirect. Everything else seemed to cause issues or not work 100% of the time.

```
# Remove www
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]
</IfModule>

# Always secure
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule (.*) https://domain.com%{REQUEST_URI}
</IfModule>

# Remove index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteCond $1 !\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code works great for me, and utitlizes a 301 redirect so that you can keep any existing pagerank for SEO! I add this before the code that removes index.php.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On

    #force SSL
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This code gives me "Error, to many redirects"

Comment: @podarok Do you have any other redirect scripts in place that may be conflicting?

Comment: Yup, sorry about that
There was a redirect handler added in HAProxy config in front of the apache. So nevermind my previous comment